# Disable search suggestions in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, search

When i use the search in Windows 8.1, under the results like software and files, there is a sort of suggestion, and if I click on it it opens a search results page in Windows. How do I disable that? I've already disabled the Bing suggestions so it isn't that.

Here is a screenshot.
[image]
  I mean the "assistente vocale" text at the bottom of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Open the charm bar (swipe from the right).

Click Change PC Settings

Under the option `Search` you can enable/disable it.

You can also delete the history

Comment: I've already disabled that but the text still remains